# Calling a method before a task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way in rails to call a method, such as before, automatically when running a rake task I've built?

Let's say we have

```
namespace :migrate do

  def before
    # do this before all tasks 
  end

  desc 'migrate authors from legacy database'
  task :authors => :environment do
    # some code here
  end

end
```

I want to the before method to run everytime a task runs.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: http://www.rubyflow.com/items/4104

Comment: It is what I'm looking for but when I bundle it errors "Unfortunately, the gem rake-hooks (1) has an invalid gemspec. As a result, Bundler cannot install this Gemfile. Please ask the gem author to yank the bad version to fix this issue. For more information, see http://bit.ly/syck-defaultkey."